# Binding Navigation Property with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, binding, entity-framework-4

I have another question about binding using C# and the entity framework.

Here, I'm looking to bind a navigation property to a listbox or a listview.

I saw on different posts that if I update the collection using code behind the list would not be notified because the collection does not handle notification (it's always the same problem anyway).

People suggested to use an `ObservableCollection` for example, but, and here is my question, this comes down to basically duplicate the collection and hence, if I modify it, I'd have to handle in code-behind the fact that the change has also to be applied to the "original" navigation property right?

If that's the case, I was thinking: why not create a custom property called, say, MyObservableNavigationProperty in a partial class. I could then interact only with this collection, catch the event when the collection is changed and apply the change to the "original" collection. Is that a nice way to do the trick? or am I getting all confused here....

Comment: Are your entities generated by the designer/template?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it mattered... It was generated using the designer by "importing" a database I previously created. What is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually code my entities by hand.  The flexability it provides is generally more useful than the time saved using the designer to generate some properties, especially since EF4 can [generate proxies](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/12/22/poco-proxies-part-1.aspx) to do the important tracking/lazy loading bits.

That said, if you don't have that option you could try using the [ADO.NET Self-Tracking Entity Generator Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477604.aspx) to generate your entities if possible.  The collection's it generates inherit from `ObservableCollection<T>`.

If that isn't possible, then I think your partial class solution is the way to go.